# sysjobactivity table questions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to figure out if a particular SQL Scheduled job is currently running on SQL Server 12.0.5000.0.

I was thinking I could do code similar to the following:

```
declare @jobid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

SELECT @jobid = job_id
FROM
msdb.dbo.sysjobs
where name = 'My Job Name'

select * FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity where job_id=@jobid
and start_execution_date is not null and stop_execution_date is null
```

It does find my running job.  Also if I stop the job, I see the stop_execution_date gets populated.  However, I have a bunch of other entries in the sysjobactivity that have a populated start_execution_date and a NULL stop_execution_date.  Do you know what these could be?

Thanks

Comment: By the way, do you know how to write a joined query?

Comment: You mean like a LEFT OUTER JOIN, that type of thing?  I'm still trying to figure out out to figure out which jobs are currently running.  That still seems a bit tricky.  Looks like it's probably easier to do in C#, calling the sp_help_job

Comment: I strongly suggest you learn basic joins, it's the first step to knowing anything in SQL. `select * FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity a join msdb.dbo.sysjobs j
on where j.job_id = a.jobid where j.name = 'My Job Name' and a.start_execution_date is not null and a.stop_execution_date is null`